# Unable to pass function to a child component in ReactJS

Tags: reactjs, react-props

I have 2 files.

App.js

```
class App extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      todos: ToDoData,
    };
  }

  handleChange(id) {
    console.log("changed", id);
  }

  render() {
    const ToDoItems = this.state.todos.map(function (content) {
      return (
        <ToDoItem
          key={content.id}
          content={content}
          handleChange={this.handleChange}
        />
      );
    });

    return <div>{ToDoItems}</div>;
  }
}
```

And ToDoitem.js

```
function ToDoItem(props) {
  console.log(props);
  return (
    <label className="container">
      <input
        type="checkbox"
        checked={props.content.is_complete}
        onChange={() => props.handleChange(props.content.id)}
      />
      {props.content.title}
      <br />
    </label>
  );
}
```

It says

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'handleChange' of undefined

```
  20 |     <ToDoItem
  21 |       key={content.id}
  22 |       content={content}
> 23 |       handleChange={this.handleChange}
     | ^  24 |     />
  25 |   );
  26 | });
```

I am following a tutorial and exactly this same code works for them but not for me. Where am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This appears to be a scoping issue - the classic JS "this" dilemma.

Try swap:

`const ToDoItems = this.state.todos.map(function (content) {`

to

`const ToDoItems = this.state.todos.map((content) => {`

This approach will keep "this" in scope

Comment: OMG THIS WORKS. I couldn't believe that it was such a simple issue. I thought function and arrow function were equals. i never noticed it.

Comment: Great. If it works for you make sure to upvote/mark as correct to let others know it is correct. Its actually a pretty tricky problem - "this" in JS is infamous for being a PITA. Our functions give us a way around them

Comment: we can also handle it via handleChange={_this.handleChange} ? Or that won't work?

Comment: The `_this` approach could work (but you would need to define `_this = this` somewhere. I would say that approach is the way to do it pre-ES6 (it was a work around). 
I would use either an arrow function or bind (like mentioned in the other answer) over _this

Answer (score 2):

```
class App extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      todos: ToDoData,
    };

    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
  }

  handleChange(id) {
    console.log("changed", id);
  }

  render() {
    const _this = this;
    const ToDoItems = this.state.todos.map(function (content) {
      return (
        <ToDoItem
          key={content.id}
          content={content}
          handleChange={_this.handleChange}
        />
      );
    });

    return <div>{ToDoItems}</div>;
  }
}
```

You need to add `this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this)` and save this into _this variable because could not access this in callback.